# mongodb lookup in array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

when i do a lookup in mongodb i enter an as field and the data is loaded into this field. But if I have an array of objects and one of the fields is a REF field then I always have the problem that the data from the lookup is always loaded into a separate field and I cannot find it with the array. How can I do a lookup that loads the data directly into the array element.

for example

i have a organisation with an array of users and there status and role in the organisation

```
{
_id: "60cc87da3a530000173f6d33",
"baseData": {
    "name": "Organisation 1",
    "email": "org@gmail.com",
    "image": "",
    "description": "desc",
    "users": [
        {
           userID: "60cc87803a530000173f6d2d",
           userStatus: "active" ,
           userOrgRole: "Admin"
        },
        {
           userID: "60cc87803a530000173f9h4u",
           userStatus: "active" ,
           userOrgRole: "User"
        }
    ]
  }
}
```

when i made a lookup an define the as field as baseData.users the user array are overwirte with the user data. But how i can add the data to each users array.

for example this is the result i need

```
{
_id: "60cc87da3a530000173f6d33",
"baseData": {
    "name": "Organisation 1",
    "email": "org@gmail.com",
    "image": "",
    "description": "desc",
    "users": [
        {
           userID: "60cc87803a530000173f6d2d",
           userStatus: "active" ,
           userOrgRole: "Admin"
           // userdata data from lookup for each array
        },
        {
           userID: "60cc87803a530000173f9h4u",
           userStatus: "active" ,
           userOrgRole: "User"
           // userdata data from lookup for each array
        }
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this way, add these stages to aggregation pipeline. It will help to add user details..

```
 {  
       $unwind: {
                    path: "$baseData.users",
                    preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true,
                }, 
     },
     {
       $lookup: {
                    from: "users", // replace with your collection name
                    localField: "baseData.users.userID",
                    foreignField: "_id",
                    as: "baseData.users",
                },
    },
    {
        $group: {
                    _id: "$_id",
                    baseData: {
                        $push: "$baseData",
                    },
                },
    },
```